# Music replay does not work on Libgdx

Tags: audio, libgdx

I have a sound track for my game, which I play when player enters a level, and stop when the level ended. 
Sound track is a Music class with looping set to true, and loaded through an AssetManager.

It works fine for the first level, I can hear the music, and when the level ends, I call stop. On the start of the second level, I cal start again, but I cannot hear any music. There is no error or exception either. 
From the documentation, I thought I can user the same Music class instance, so theoretically it should work AFAIK.
Any idea why it doesn't work?

Comment: The LibGdx class works fine, so it's likely to be something else in your code. Could you include some please?

Comment: The fact that there's no error makes me wonder if it's a problem with disposing the music before you're done with it. From what I've seen while I played with LibGDX, disposing a texture earlier than required will lead to invisible Sprites. It's very possible you have an "invisible" Music going on here.